# Links are not working when registering page with as: '...' option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a page called Event which I want to call differently so I overwrote it using `as: '...'`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event, as: "MySite" do
...
end
```

but now the links on a specific event page are not working.

```
sidebar "Additional options", only: [:show] do
  ul do
    li link_to "Download CSV ", generate_csv_admin_event_path(resource, format: :csv)
  end
end
```

The error I get is `undefined method 'generate_csv_admin_event_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::SidebarSection:0x00007fe54d0e7308>`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.generate_csv_admin_event_path(resource, format: :csv)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that and got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'generate_csv_admin_event_path' for #<Module:0x00007fe55ddd58e8>
Did you mean?  generate_csv_admin_my_site_path?` which explains that AA generates routes dynamically.
`